# Event ID 4104 SmallBusinessServer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-sbs-2003

I get the following error on SBS server 2003:

> Event ID 4104 SmallBusinessServer Could not connect to the monitoring
>   database. This can occur when there are multiple connections to the
>   database. Wait a short period of time, and then try again. If this
>   error persists, run the Monitoring Configuration Wizard, and select
>   Reinstall monitoring features.

The solution I found tells me to reinstall the service:

> 1. Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Add or Remove Programs.
> 2. Select Windows Small Business Server 2003 and then click Change/Remove. The Setup Wizard appears.
> 3. Click Next to start the wizard.
> 4. On the Windows Configuration page, click Next.
> 5. On the Component Selection page, in the Action column, change Server Tools to Maintenance, change Monitoring component to Remove,
>      and then click Next.
> 6. On the Component Summary page, click Next.
> 7. Click Finish.
>
> B. Uninstall Microsoft SQL Server Desktop Engine (SBSMONITORING).
>
> In Add or Remove Programs, select Microsoft SQL Server Desktop Engine
>   (SBSMONITORING) and then click Remove. A dialog box appears. To
>   confirm your actions, click Yes.
>
> C. Delete registry keys.
>
> 1. Delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SmallBusinessServer\Monitoring.
> 2. Delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SBSMONITORING.
>
> D. Delete the IIS Virtual Directory.
>
> 1. Open IIS, expand servername, Web Sites, Default Web Site.
> 2. Delete Monitoring.
>
> E. Rename folders.
>
> 1. Rename C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL$SBSMONITORING to MSSQL$SBSMONITORING.OLD.
> 2. Rename C:\Inetpub\monitoring to monitoring.old.
>
> F. Install the Monitoring component.
>
> 1. In Add or Remove Programs, select Windows Small Business Server 2003 and then click Change/Remove. The Setup Wizard appears.
> 2. Click Next.
> 3. On the Windows Configuration page, click Next.
> 4. On the Component Selection page, in the Action column, change Server Tools to Maintenance, change Monitoring component to Install,
>      and then click Next.
> 5. On the Logon Information page, click Next.
> 6. On the Component Summary page, click Next.
> 7. Click Finish.

My question is, what do I do to reconfigure it after the re-install?  Would I even need to?  Any KBs on that?  Any suggestions?  Anything else I can do before reinstalling?

**NOTE:**  I have tried & successfully restarted the services to no help.

Please help!  Thanks!

**EDIT (14.VIII.2012, 10.25, @JMeterX)**

Here is the screenshot of what I was talking about:

[image]

Of course it's also possible the monitoring was never configured...

**EDIT (15.I.2013, 17.20)**

Just so, I can award an answer and move on with this question, what are the steps for me to find out if the SBS monitoring was ever configured on the server?

Answer (score 3):

Before reinstalling I would check to see if your Database is in single-user mode?  Or possibly check the `user connections` option to ensure it is set to 0 which will allow the connections to grow as needed.  It has been awhile since I worked with SBS but I believe there is a wizard that you run that sets up monitoring reports.

You could also try recreating the database (as an admin):

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Small Business Server\Bin\MoveDataPowerShellHost.exe"
```

Run the script:

```
C:\windows\temp\Create-SBSMonitoringDb.ps1
```

**EDIT**
With 2003 you should follow [these](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555432) instructions to reinstall the service.  It will come down to which you prefer to try your own that you found or these.  I know you were looking for "official" documentation.  The link is a KB article.

or:

1. Control Panel -> Add Remove Program -> Windows Small Business Server 2003. Set Server Tools to Maintenance. Set Monitoring to Uninstall and continue the setup process.
2. Control Panel -> Add Remove Program -> Microsoft SQL Server Desktop Engine (SBSMonitoring) -> Remove.
3. Rename the C:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL$SBSMONITORING Folder.
4. Reboot the server.
5. Control Panel -> Add Remove Program -> Windows Small Business Server 2003. Set Server Tools to Maintenance. Set Monitoring to Install and continue the setup process.
6. Reboot the server.
7. Start MSSQL$SBSMONITORING and SQLAgent$SBSMONITORING services.
8. In Server Management Console -> Monitoring and Reporting: run the "Set Up Monitoring Reports and Alerts wizard".

Comment: Thanks for your help, but 1st, my SBS directory is slightly different (C:\Program Files\Windows for Small Business Server).  I have no Bin sub-folder in there.  I am gonna post a screenshot for you.  And I don't have that script either, unless, of course, I need to create it.

Comment: @George my apologies, I was in the 2011 mindset. This then is not an option for 2003. Have you checked your user connections setting in the Microsoft SQL DB to ensure its value set at 0?  I believe recreating the database for 2003 can be a bit of a disaster.  I would recommend the following which I will add to my answer.